# Meaning of std::forward<std::decay_t<F>>(f)

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, move-semantics, perfect-forwarding

I have a question about the code written in https://koturn.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/06/10/060000
When I pass a left value reference, if I do not remove the reference with std::decay_t, I get an error.
Here is the error message
**'error: 'operator()' is not a member of 'main()::<lambda(auto:11, int)>&**
I don't understand why it is necessary to exclude the left value reference.
I would like to know what this error means.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>


template <typename F>
class
FixPoint : private F
{
public:
  explicit constexpr FixPoint(F&& f) noexcept
    : F{std::forward<F>(f)}
  {}

  template <typename... Args>
  constexpr decltype(auto)
  operator()(Args&&... args) const
  {
    return F::operator()(*this, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};  // class FixPoint


namespace
{
template <typename F>
inline constexpr decltype(auto)
makeFixPoint(F&& f) noexcept
{
  return FixPoint<std::decay_t<F>>{std::forward<std::decay_t<F>>(f)};
}
}  // namespace


int
main()
{
  auto body = [](auto f, int n) -> int {
    return n < 2 ? n : (f(n - 1) + f(n - 2));
  };
  auto result = makeFixPoint(body)(10);
  std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `std::decay` with `std::forward`.  Most likely you just need `return FixPoint<std::decay_t<F>>{std::forward<F>(f)};`

Comment: Thanks for replying.
I was wondering the same thing too.
I did so and encountered the following error　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　**prog.cc:29:54: error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type 'main()::<lambda(auto:11, int)>&&' to lvalue of type 'main()::<lambda(auto:11, int)>'
   29 |   return FixPoint<std::decay_t<F>>{std::forward<F>(f)};
      |                                                      ^
prog.cc:10:35: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'constexpr FixPoint<F>::FixPoint(F&&) [with F = main()::<lambda(auto:11, int)>]'
   10 |   explicit constexpr FixPoint(F&& f) noexcept**

Comment: @NathanOliver: if one decays the type, the forward is not necessary imo, `FixPoint<std::decay_t<F>>{f};` should suffice. (But it also doesn't hurt.) At least this holds for "normal" objects, I'm not taking account on the 37+x differenct decay mechanisms, though.

Comment: I see your point.
Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

,The code you have shared is toxic.

```
template <typename F>
class FixPoint : private F
{
public:
  explicit constexpr FixPoint(F&& f)
```

what this means is that we expect `F` to be a value type (because inheriting from a reference isn't possible).  In addition, we will only accept rvalues -- we will *only* move from another `F`.

```
  : F{std::forward<F>(f)}
{}
```

this `std::forward<F>` is pointless; this indicates that the person writing this code *thinks* they are perfect forwarding: they are not.  The only legal types `F` are value types (not references), and if `F` is a value type `F&&` is always an rvalue reference, and thus `std::forward<F>` is always equivalent to `std::move`.

There are cases where you want to

```
template<class X>
struct wrap1 {
  X&& x;
  wrap1(X&& xin):x(std::forward<X>(xin)){}
};
```

or even

```
template<class X>
struct wrap2 {
  X x;
  wrap2(X&& xin):x(std::forward<X>(xin)){}
};
```

so the above code is *similar* to some use cases, but it isn't one of those use cases.  (The difference here is that `X` or `X&&` is the type of a member, not a base class; base classes cannot be references).

The use for `wrap2` is when you want to "lifetime extend" rvalues, and simply take references to lvalues.  The use for `wrap1` is when you want to continue the perfect forwarding of some expression (`wrap1` style objects are generally unsafe to keep around for more than a single line of code; `wrap2` are safe so long as they don't outlive any lvalue passed to them).

---

```
template <typename F>
inline constexpr decltype(auto)
makeFixPoint(F&& f) noexcept
{
  return FixPoint<std::decay_t<F>>{std::forward<std::decay_t<F>>(f)};
}
```

Ok more red flags here.  `inline constexpr` is a sign of nonsense; `constexpr` functions are always `inline`.  There could be some compilers who treat the extra `inline` as meaning something, so not a guarantee of a problem.

```
return FixPoint<std::decay_t<F>>{std::forward<std::decay_t<F>>(f)};
```

`std::forward` is a conditional move.  It moves if there is an rvalue or value type passed to it.  `decay` is guaranteed to return a value type.  So we just threw out the conditional part of the operation, and made it into a raw move.

```
return FixPoint<std::decay_t<F>>{std::move(f)};
```

this is a simpler one that has the same meaning.

At this point you'll probably see the danger:

```
template <typename F>
constexpr decltype(auto)
makeFixPoint(F&& f) noexcept
{
  return FixPoint<std::decay_t<F>>{std::move(f)};
}
```

we are unconditionally moving from the `makeFixPoint` argument.  There is nothing about the name `makeFixPoint` that says "I move from the argument", and it accept forwarding references; so it will silently consume an lvalue and move-from it.

This is very rude.

---

So a sensible version of the code is:

```
template <typename F>
class FixPoint : private F
{
public:
  template<class U,
    class dU = std::decay_t<U>,
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<dU, FixPoint> && std::is_same_v<dU, F>, bool> = true
  >
  explicit constexpr FixPoint(U&& u) noexcept
    : F{std::forward<U>(u)}
  {}
```

[SNIP]

```
namespace
{
  template <typename F>
  constexpr FixPoint<std::decay_t<F>>
  makeFixPoint(F&& f) noexcept
  {
    return FixPoint<std::decay_t<F>>{std::forward<F>(f)};
  }
}  // namespace
```

that cleans things up a bit.

Comment: I learned a lot from your answers!
I understand that the code I posted is dangerous.
However, even if I use your code, it does not eliminate the error where f is passed as a left value reference.　 **error: base specifier must name a class
FixPoint : private F**  　Why does it pass the left value reference to the inherited F even if it is constrained by template?

Comment: @gath I assume your `makeFixPoint` does not match exactly the version I posted at bottom of my answer.  You have to `decay` the TYPE passed to the class, but forward the value.  I also fixed a typo... aha that is why!  Explicit ctor.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand why it is necessary to exclude the left value
> reference. I would like to know what this error means.

When you pass an *lvalue* lambda into `makeFixPoint()`, the template parameter `F` of `makeFixPoint()` is instantiated as `L&`, where `L` is the lambda type. In the function body, `FixPoint<std::decay_t<F>>{...}` will be instantiated as `FixPoint<L>{...}`, so the constructor of `FixPoint` is instantiated as

```
explicit constexpr FixPoint(L&& f);
```

which accepts a lambda type of *rvalue* reference. In `makeFixPoint()`, if you initialize it with `{std::forward<F>(f)}` i.e. `{std::forward<L&>(f)}`, `f` will be forwarded as an *lvalue*, which will be ill-formed since *rvalue* reference cannot bind an *lvalue*.

The purpose of using `{std::forward<std::decay_t<F>>(f)}` is to force `f` to be forwarded as an *rvalue*.

Answer (score 0):

The template just can't work as intended this way.

First, because it is supposed to be possible to inherit from `F`, it doesn't make much sense to use `std::decay_t`. Instead it is probably supposed to be just `std::remove_cvref_t`, but before C++20 that was kind of cumbersome to write and `std::decay_t` does almost the same.

In the class template `F` is intended to be a non-reference type. It is not a template parameter of the constructor. So it cannot be used for perfect-forwarding. The constructor argument will always be a rvalue reference which cannot take lvalues.

Even if a lvalue is passed to `makeFixPoint`, the call `std::forward<std::decay_t<F>>(f)` forces conversion to a rvalue reference, which then can be used in the constructor. That is clearly dangerous. The function *always* behaves as if you had `std::move`d the argument into it.

It should just be `std::forward<F>(f)` and the constructor should take another template parameter that can be used to form a forwarding reference:

```
template<typename G>
requires std::is_same_v<std::remove_cvref_t<G>, F>
explicit constexpr FixPoint(G&& g) noexcept
  : F{std::forward<G>(g)}
{}
```